# How to create notebook with paragraph loaded with code using zeppelin REST API

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I want to create zeppelin notebook via zeppelin REST API. 
I don't want to create an empty notebook, instead I want to create a notebook with some scala code in it.

What parameters do I need to pass to create such a notebook?
Or is it possible to clone a notebook with some small modifications. Like, I can have a template notebook with parametrized fields. During clone, I will replace the parameters with actual value. Is it possible to do that?

Unfortunately the [Sample JSON input](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/rest-api/rest-json/rest-json-notebook-create.json) in [zeppelin document](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/rest-api/rest-notebook.html) is not loading. I am getting the following error.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /docs/rest-api/rest-json/rest-json-notebook-create.json was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, currently there is no API to create notebook with paragraphs loaded with code.

I've extended API to do that.

Refer, https://github.com/samuel-pt/incubator-zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-server/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/rest/ParagraphRestApi.java

Answer (score 0):

This functionality had been added just [recently](https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/commit/27b7ad52b6bf8f18643e8b58d16fcab3d709eb1c).

Comment: This has provision to add notebooks. But with contents, there is no API